# QGraphicsItemGroup after removall not able to add new

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qmouseevent

I am  attaching  scene_ on  QGraphicsView

```
QGraphicsItem* scene_ = new QGraphicsScene(this);
setScene(scene_);
```

on scene  I am  adding 2 things

```
QGraphicsItem* prev_pixmap_item_ = scene_->addPixmap(pm);
scene_->addItem(prev_pixmap_item_);    
prev_pixmap_item_->setZValue (0);

QGraphicsItemGroup *roiToolGraphicsItem = new  QGraphicsItemGroup();
scene_->addItem(roiToolGraphicsItem);
roiToolGraphicsItem->setZValue(1);
```

I am  able to add  QGraphicsItem on scene  ..

but when I remove once  using this cmd  .. after that I am not able to redraw

```
scene_->removeItem(roiToolGraphicsItem);
```

Please  can someone help/

Second I need help .. I need mouse event on QGraphicsItem  .. mouse  Selected Qgraphicsitem I can able to  identify so that I can take some action on that

Your  help will be highly appreciated

Comment: What means "I am not able to redraw"? Describe your problem more specifically.

Comment: Once running this cmd   scene_->removeItem(roiToolGraphicsItem);   if I do  view_->DrawRectangle(rect, color);  I am not able to draw again  ..

Comment: Great. Now show the code of `DrawRectangle`.